# How to implement on scrolldown pagination in Angular 4

Tags: angular, scroll-paging

I am new in angular 4. I want to implement scroll pagination in angular 4. Initially I want to show 20 records.
After scroll down I want to show next 20. I will do the same till end of list.

I tried to implement it using "angular2-infinite-scroll". but I am not able to show initially first 20 records as well scroll data.

component file :

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'angular2-infinite-scroll';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-scroll',
      templateUrl: `./scroll.component.html`,
      styleUrls: ['./scroll.component.css']
    })
    export class ScrollComponent implements OnInit {

    let item = [{
        "Name": "XYz Compnay"
    },
    {
        "Name": "XYz Company1"
    }, {
        "Name": "XYz Company2"
    }, {
        "Name": "XYz Company3"
    }, {
        "Name": "XYz Company4"
    }, {
        "Name": "XYz Company5"
    }];
      constructor() {}
      ngOnInit() {}

      onScroll () {
        alert('scrolled!!');    
      }

     }
```

HTML file :

```
<div
         infinite-scroll
         [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
         [infiniteScrollThrottle]="10"
         (scrolled)="onScroll()"
         >
      <p *ngFor="let items of item">
        {{items.Name}}
      </p>
    </div>
```

If anyone having about it please share same.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I recommend using [ngx-infinite-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll) against `angular2-infinite-scroll` due to new features and compatibility 
with AOT.

First you need to specify the `scrollWindow` property if you are not using the whole window and using `overflow: scroll` 
property to emulate a scrollable div. Also in your `ScrollComponent` class you need to have `item` as a property of class
and not a variable, so you should use `public item` instead of `let item`.

If the size of list is already known than you can leverage `infiniteScrollDisabled` to improve performance.

Also as it is grammatically incorrect to name multiple things as `item` and call single thing an `item`. I am going
to change `item` to `items` ( You can see that in the ngFor loop in template html )

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    styles: [`
    .search-results {
        height: 100px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
    `],
    template: `
    <div class="search-results"
    infiniteScroll
    [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
    [infiniteScrollThrottle]="50"
    (scrolled)="onScroll()"
    [infiniteScrollDisabled]="isFullListDisplayed"
    [scrollWindow]="false">
        <p *ngFor="let item of itemsToShow; let i = index">
        {{i + ' ' + item.Name}}
        </p>
    </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    private noOfItemsToShowInitially: number = 5;
    // itemsToLoad - number of new items to be displayed
    private itemsToLoad: number = 5;
    // 18 items loaded for demo purposes
    private items = [
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company0"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company1"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company2"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company3"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company4"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company5"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company6"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company7"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company8"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company9"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company10"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company11"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company12"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company13"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company14"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company15"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company16"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYz Company17"
        }
    ];
    // List that is going to be actually displayed to user
    public itemsToShow = this.items.slice(0, this.noOfItemsToShowInitially);
    // No need to call onScroll if full list has already been displayed
    public isFullListDisplayed: boolean = false;

    onScroll() {
        if (this.noOfItemsToShowInitially <= this.items.length) {
            // Update ending position to select more items from the array
            this.noOfItemsToShowInitially += this.itemsToLoad;
            this.itemsToShow = this.items.slice(0, this.noOfItemsToShowInitially);
            console.log("scrolled");
        } else {
            this.isFullListDisplayed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You will now successfully see an alert message when you scroll down the list.

Here is a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BITfVoBRqRYCHknNjSWt?p=preview) of above code.

Comment: If I have 1000 record and I want to display 50 records first time if user scroll down then again user will see next 5o records. please consider above example as prototype for same

Comment: I have updated my answer and plunker. Instead of 1000 record i have used 18 and instead of displaying 50 records, i have first displayed 5 and then next 5.

Comment: If I want to implement the same on basis API call. Like https://myweb.com/api/todolist/1. I mean according to page number there will be API call. If I will scroll there will be another API call with next page number.

Comment: Yes, there will be another API call and u will have to push it to the existing array.